# Converting string to date with a different timezone gives the wrong date

Tags: swift, timezone

So, this:

```
import Foundation

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Australia/Currie")!

let todayString = (df.string(from: Date()))
print(todayString)

let today = df.date(from: todayString)!
print(today)
```

Prints:

```
2021-02-19
2021-02-18 13:00:00 +0000
```

For reference, today’s date based on my current timezone is the 18th. So it correctly prints the 19th when using an Australian timezone that moves the time ahead.

What I don't understand is why `today` is a day behind `todayString`, since it's constructed from the same `DateFormatter`. Ideally, they should both print the 19th, right?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have both a date (from a different timezone) and its string representation.

Comment: When you print directly a `Date` instance, which is what you do last, the GMT version of the date gets printed.

Comment: Think of `Date` as a universal way to store a date and `DateFormatter` like a way to display the same date in different time zones.

Comment: Thanks! How would I get `today` to reflect the timezone then?

Comment: You have to use `string(from:)` function of your `DateFormatter` like you did in the first `print`. `Date` does not store time zone information.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `print` displays `Date` instances always in UTC(+0000). For example check

```
let date = Date()
print(date)
```

To `print` the date in your current locale (and time zone) write

```
print(today.description(with: .current))
```